# Open php in same index.html

Tags: php, html

So I have a php file in a form in index.html and when I submit the form and the php file opens, it opens at /xxx.php instead of just in the main index site, how do I make it open in the index site?

update: i fixed so the php is at the main index site, but now the image will not appear when submitting a username

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
div {
font family: Ubuntu;
background-color: #F2F2F2;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<h1> <center> Instagram Full Size Profile Picture </center> </h1>
</div>
<center>
<form action="" method="get">
Enter Instagram Username: <input type="text" name="input">
<input type="submit" value="View">
</form>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

-

```
<?php
$name = $_REQUEST['input'];
echo $name;
echo "<br>";
$output = shell_exec("/var/www/html/instapic.sh $name");
echo "<img src=$output>";
?>
```

-

```
#!/bin/bash
NAME=$1
#curl -s https://www.instagram.com/$NAME/ | grep image | grep fbma | sed 's,s150x150/,,g' | cut -f 4 -f '"'
curl -s https://www.instagram.com/$NAME/ | grep "og:image" | sed 's,s150x150/,,g' | cut -f 4 -f '"'
```

Comment: Can you post what have you done ?

Comment: I'm guessing you mean you don't want the URL to change?

Comment: Sounds like you need to learn how to use AJAX.

Comment: please post code snippets

Comment: @CD001 yes exactly

Comment: You can either change index.html to index.php and post the form to itself - or use Ajax - or use some URL Rewriting trickery... kinda broad and you've not shown anything you've tried.

Comment: code now posted @Kamotho

Comment: code now posted @Lucarnosky

Answer (score 0):

See the tag `<form action="xxx.php" method="post">` on the top the form.

If i didn't wrong the form redirect to a page "xxx.php" you need change name to "Index.php"

Answer (score 0):

leave your action attribute of your form tag blank like below

```
<form action="" .....
```

> NOTE : Your php code won't work in file with extension .html so change that to .php (if you had not changed that setting in apache)

Comment: yes ok thanks, but now the php isnt linked at all? how do i make the form open the php file now?

Comment: @LOGH there is no need for it. Php scripts runs on server side, so whenever anyone submit your form, your code will be executed on server and response will sen to browser.

Comment: update your code snippet in a fiddle or in your question to easy to check.